# Add-Content bytes fails with PowerShell Core

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm using PowerShell Core v6.0.2, and trying to write out an array of bytes to a file. This works fine in regular PowerShell but fails with PowerShell Core

```
$jsonstr = Get-Content $inputfilename
$jsonfile = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonstr
$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($jsonfile.data)

$outputfilename = "test.xlsx";

Add-Content -Path $outputfilename -Value $bytes -Encoding Byte
```

Error:

[image]

Is this is a bug or can Byte no longer be used because of binary ordering issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this blog [post](https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2017/12/powershell-core-does-not-have-encoding-byte-replaced-with-new-parameter-asbytestream.html), on PowerShell Core you need to use Set-Content with the AsByteStream parameter.

I've changed my script to the following:

```
$jsonstr = Get-Content $inputfilename
$jsonfile = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonstr
$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($jsonfile.data)

$outputfilename = "test.xlsx";
Set-Content -Path $outputfilename -Value $bytes -AsByteStream
```